# Copying second occurrence pattern to a new file in sed

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, certificates

I have a certificate file which has 2 certificates in it. Starts with `---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--` and ends with `---END CERTIFICATE----`.

Example:

```
---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--
blah1 blah1
---END CERTIFICATE----

---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--
blah2 blah2
---END CERTIFICATE----
```

I want the second set to be copied to another file.

I have tried following `sed` command but its copying both the certificate to `public.cer`.

```
sed -n '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/w public.cer' intermediate.cer
```

How to copy only the second certificate to a new file?

Answer (score 3):

With **`awk`** *range patterns*:

```
awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ && ++c==2,/END CERTIFICATE/' intermediate.cer > public.cer
```

---

The contents of `public.cer` file:

```
---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--
blah2 blah2
---END CERTIFICATE----
```

---

A *range pattern* is made of two patterns separated by a comma, in the form `begpat, endpat`. It is used to match ranges of consecutive input records. The first pattern, `begpat`, controls where the range begins, while `endpat` controls where the pattern ends. The counter, `c` is incremented and checked upon every line matching `/BEGIN_CERTIFICATE/`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing directly to a file, you can collect all certs in the hold space with `H`, then on the last line (`$!d` stops processing for all lines but the last one, so everything after this is done only for the last line) move the hold space to the pattern space with `g` and remove what you want to drop before writing:

```
sed -n '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/H;$!d;g;s/.*\(---BEGIN\)/\1/;w public.cer'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another sed if we can't find END after blah2

```
sed ':A;$bB;/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/!d;N;/END CERTIFICATE/!bA;h;$!d;:B;x;w public.cer' intermediate.cer
```